# Maven Clean: excluding directory inside target from being deleted

Tags: maven, maven-clean-plugin

I have tried many variants but could not make this work. One example (child `pom.xml`):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>target</directory>
                <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>myFolder</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Maven always tries to delete my folder. Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As also suggested by @AR.3 in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41024461/1746118), the `clean` phase and goal would -

> By default, it discovers and deletes the directories configured in
> project.build.directory, project.build.outputDirectory,
> project.build.testOutputDirectory, and
> project.reporting.outputDirectory.

Still, if you want to exclude a specific folder from being deleted you can follow the inverse approach(a simple hack) to do it as follows -

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0</version>
       <configuration>
           <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
           <filesets>
                <fileset>
                    <directory>target</directory>
                    <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
                    <includes>
                          <include><!--everything other that what you want to exclude--></include>
                    </includes>
                 </fileset>
            </filesets>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

More about `excludeDefaultDirectories` from a [similar link](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html#excludeDefaultDirectories) -

> Disables the deletion of the default output directories configured for
> a project. *If set to true, only the files/directories selected via the
> parameter filesets will be deleted*.

**EDIT**

It is indeed possible to exclude a specific folder from being deleted using a direct approach:

```
<configuration>
    <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>target</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude><!-- folder to exclude --></exclude>
                </excludes>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. I could make it work directly using the following: <configuration>
     <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
     <filesets>
      <fileset>
       <directory>target</directory>
       <includes>
        <include>**</include>
       </includes>
       <excludes>
        <exclude>myFolder</exclude>
       </excludes>
      </fileset>
     </filesets>
    </configuration>

Comment: @ftkg - Indeed. Please feel free to edit the answer updating the exact regexes used.

Comment: I'm a maven newbie, so apologies if I'm asking the obvious... Given your second solution above, is there a way to only skip cleaning stuff out if a flag is passed into maven, like `-DskipCleaningMyStuff=true` (and default to `false` (i.e. clean all by default)?

Comment: The `/**` is required after the excuded folder's name if you also want to save all of its subdirectores. Like so: `<exclude>folder-and-subfolders/**<exclude>`

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation of the `clean:clean` goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html):

> This attempts to clean a project's working directory of the files that were generated at build-time. By default, it discovers and deletes the directories configured in `project.build.directory`, `project.build.outputDirectory`, `project.build.testOutputDirectory`, and `project.reporting.outputDirectory`.
>
> **Files outside the default may also be included in the deletion by configuring the `filesets` tag.**

This means that whatever you declare in the `filesets` element, the `target` directory will always be deleted (**EDIT** unless `excludeDefaultDirectories` is set to true, see below edit). Given the above description, a workaround is to do the following:

1. Temporarily override the above properties to point to something other than the default `target` directory, *before* cleaning the directories.
2. Use the `filesets` mechanism to tell which directories to exclude from the `target` directory (same as what you already did).
3. Restore the properties *after* cleaning the directories.

The `pre-clean` and `post-clean` lifecycle phases can be used to do steps 1 and 3.

**EDIT:** (thanks to nullpointer for pointing it out)

Setting the goal parameter `excludeDefaultDirectories` to true will exclude the default directory from being deleted, in which case you can use the `filesets` approach without the hack of overriding the Maven properties.

Comment: Well I guess there is a workaround on the same link shared by you. Thanks. :)

Comment: @nullpointer Indeed I totally missed the `excludeDefaultDirectories` parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment by @Christian, this solution uses a profile to determine whether or not to let maven-clean delete the excluded folder (and subfolders with `/**`). In my use case, a process generates parser source files in `target/generated-sources` prior to compilation. I usually want to keep them to save time. I'm also lazy (like most of us developers) and don't like to type. Commands to build the project:

1. Profile inactive, keep the parser source: `mvn clean install`
2. Profile activated, *really, truly* clean: `mvn clean install delete-parsers`

The code:

```
<properties>
    <!-- By default, clean will skip the parser source files
         generated in this folder and its subfolders.  -->
    <skip.parser.source>generated-sources/**</skip.parser.source>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <!-- Activate this profile to delete parser sources. -->
    <profile>
        <id>delete-parsers</id>
        <!-- Setting this property to null removes the exclusion 
             in maven-clean.  -->
        <properties>
            <skip.parser.source />
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <!-- Required so maven standard folders won't be deleted. -->
    <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
    <filesets>
        <fileset>
            <!-- Delete everything in target/** -->
            <directory>target</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <!-- But NOT this folder when the profile is activated. -->
            <excludes>
                <exclude>${skip.parser.source}</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileset>
    </filesets>
</configuration>
```